# How to keep the tab chars in the content of an HTML textarea when putting it in a variable in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, variables, tabs, char, textarea

I would like to know how to keep the tab chars in the content of an HTML textarea when putting it in a variable in jQuery. The explanation is as below:
I have a form containing a textarea and a button. The problem is that when I put a text containing some tab chars (For example, like what is below. As you can see, there is a tab char between "Chappell Hill" and "TX" and there is another tab char between "TX" and "77426"):

```
Chappell Hill   TX  77426
```

then I click on the button, a pop-up message displays the text without any tab chars, exactly as below:

> Chappell HillTX77426

This is the jQuery code that I have:

```
$("#massmetrotagupdate").on("click", ".update_form", 
    var note_text = $("#note_text").val();          
    alert(note_text);
});
```

So, my question is: How can I keep the tab chars in the variable `note_text` and even display what I type exactly in the textarea in the pop-message (without deleting the tab chars)? Is there any solution for that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how you can add tab char inside textarea?

Comment: Actually, I copied this text: `Chappell Hill TX 77426` from a Bloc-notes file and I pasted it in the textarea.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the text works fine - it's just that `alert()` doesn't display the tabs properly.  Use `console.log()` to display the text instead and you'll see that they are all present and correct.

(Probably you were just using `alert()` for debugging, but if you really do need to display the text using `alert()`, you could use `.replace("\x09", " ")` to change the tabs into spaces for display purposes.)

Comment: Well, I tried `console.log(note_text);` instead of `alert(note_text);` But I didn't see anything on my screen. What is wrong?

Comment: Press your F12 key to the show the console.  (If you're going to be doing any browser-based development, it would be a very good investment of your time to learn how to use the F12 developer tools.)